# Need to know more about IFLA_EVENT

Tags: c, networking, netlink, network-interface

The purpose of this thread is to validate if my statement is true or not.

From what I have read from the little data present on the internet I found out that
This IFLA_EVENT can detect any change in the network interface (IPv4/IPv6/interface up-down).

My purpose is to create a network monitor that will detect whether an interface change has happened. I have created one and could see that this flag is able to detect the addition of a new interface, IP change, and Netmask change.

I want to make sure that the above-written statement holds true or not for any architecture. If possible can anyone please provide some document that can validate the above statements?

Any comment is appreciated.